# Oozie Installation - Error during oozied.sh start

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I'm new to Oozie and I'm trying to install and setup Oozie. I am following the instructions provided on the Apache site: "http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/DG_QuickStart.html#Building_Oozie". I have been able to complete the following:

1. Build the distribution executing `./mkdistro.sh -DskipTests`.
2. Downloaded ExtJs 2.2 and exploded into a folder **libext**
3. I already have Hadoop 1.1.2 installed and working on Ubuntu 12.04 in the AWS instance.
4. The cluster is setup as a pseudo-distributed as I'm learning
5. Updated the core-site.xml with the configuration below:

   ```
   <property>
       <name>hadoop.proxyuser.ubuntu.hosts</name>
       <value>*</value>
   </property>
   <property>
       <name>hadoop.proxyuser.ubuntu.groups</name>
       <value>*</value>
   </property>
   ```
6. Executed `oozie-setup.sh prepare-war -hadoop $HADOOP_HOME 0.20.2 -extjs libext` and received the message "oozie ready to be started"
7. Executed `ooziedb.sh create -sqlfile oozie.sql -run`.
   DB created successfully.
8. Executed

   ```
   oozied.sh start
   ```

   No errors reported just variable values printed.
9. I opened the `catalina.out` file and I see the following message:

   ```
   Oct 16, 2013 6:56:10 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin 
   WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server} Setting property 'port' to '${oozie.admin.port}' did not find a matching property. 
   Oct 16, 2013 6:56:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init 
   INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /vol-cbe153a/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/server:/vol-cbe153a/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/amd64:/vol-cbe153a/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib  
   Oct 16, 2013 6:56:11 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
   INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-0    
   Oct 16, 2013 6:56:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
   INFO: Initialization processed in 1488 ms  
   Oct 16, 2013 6:56:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
   INFO: Starting service Catalina  
   Oct 16, 2013 6:56:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
   INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.36  
   Oct 16, 2013 6:56:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor  
   INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor oozie.xml  

   ERROR: Oozie could not be started 

   REASON: org.apache.oozie.service.ServiceException: E0000: System property 'oozie.home.dir' not defined
   ```

### Stacktrace:

```
org.apache.oozie.service.ServiceException: E0000: System property 'oozie.home.dir' not defined
        at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.setOozieHome(Services.java:80)
        at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.<init>(Services.java:101)
        at org.apache.oozie.servlet.ServicesLoader.contextInitialized(ServicesLoader.java:38)
```

Can somebody help me on where the `oozie.home.dir` property needs to be set?

Comment: setting oozie home in .profile would be enough export OOZIE_HOME=/home/<user>/oozie-3.2.0-cdh4.1.2 export PATH=/home/<user>/oozie-3.2.0-cdh4.1.2/bin:

Comment: I already have $OOZIE_HOME set in .profile and PATH variable is also having the entry for $OOZIE_HOME/bin. Still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to export OOZIE PATH. It is created automatically. Did you build against your Hadoop version? Since it builds against 1.1.1 by default. You may also need to modify POM.XML for your Hadoop version. I have just installed Oozie 3.3.1 on Hadoop 1.2.1 with same configuration like yours on AWS.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Based on the responses, I've turned to the vanilla oozie 3.3.1 with hadoop 1.1.1 (default). I followed all the steps. Still it fails at the step where  oozie-start.sh (or oozied.sh start). This time I opened, catalina.out file and noticed the following error

Comment: ERROR: Oozie could not be started

REASON: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/configuration/Configuration

Stacktrace:
-----------------------------------------------------------------
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/configuration/Configuration
        at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.<init>(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:37)
        at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.<clinit>(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:34)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UgiInstrumentation.create(UgiInstrumentation.java:51)

Comment: Hi,After a while of debugging I happened to notice that the classpath was not getting set properly. I opened catalina.sh file and commented the like "CLASSPATH= ". This retained by CLASSPATH and oozie was successfully started. I'm not able to view localhost:11000/oozie. It shows a page which indicates "OOZIE WEB CONSOLE IS DISABLE". this is due to ExtJS library not being recognized. Any idea on how to enable it?.

Comment: You can follow the configuration guide.http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/DG_QuickStart.html